# Nginx: Question mark in front controller rewrite rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

Currently I have this piece of code:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

This works OK for the following:
`example.com/foo` redirects to `index.php`

However `example.com/foo?bar` doesn't work. How do you make it work?

FWIW: I don't experience this problem in Apache's mod_rewrite equivalent. Basically, I moved a site that works from Apache to Nginx. Now I experience this issue.

**Edit:**

To be clear here's what I indent to do:

- `example.com/foo`
- `example.com/foo/bar/etc`
- `example.com/foo?bar`
- `example.com/foo?bar=quz`

Should all serve `index.php` "silently" without changing the URL of the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it with the following config, and I believe this does want you want:

```
server {
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /home/www/test;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from 
server_name test.myhost.nl;

location / {        
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then as directory, then fall back to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;

    # Fix for server variables that behave differently under nginx/php-fpm than typically expected
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # Include the standard fastcgi_params file included with ngingx
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    # Override the SCRIPT_FILENAME variable set by fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    # Pass to upstream PHP-FPM; This must match whater you name your upstream connection
    #fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the it didn't work, it prompted a download of the PHP file instead. Here's my complete code: http://pastebin.com/3Nhhbu5D

Comment: hmm, in the pastebin code you're missing a `;` after try_files. If that's not the problem try adding the following block outside your php location block: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }`  also I don't recommend using an if statement to redirect the `www` part, you can use a different server block for www.yourhost.com to redirect to yourhost.com.

Comment: Sorry about the missing `;`. Here's the updated code: http://pastebin.com/yGKZYGqu. Now `example.com/foo` doesn't get redirected to `index.php`

Comment: Ok, and if you place the `location /` block above the php block? and what happens if you type `example.com/foo.php` does that get redirected?

Comment: same thing happens if `/` block was moved. `/foo.php` get's literally redirected to `index.php` with the URL in the address bar saying `example.com/index.php`. Note that in my original code above, `example.com/foo` would internally redirect to `index.php` and `example.com/foo` remains in the address bar, which is the way I intend it.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood the question. I changed my answer, is this how you want it?

Comment: The `$_GET` variables works but for some reason my `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is blank, hence it doesn't work.

Comment: This is my updated config: http://pastebin.com/G61fVxaN my PATH_INFO is blank even if I call `example.com/foo/bar`

Comment: does your php.ini contain `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` ?

Comment: You know what, I'm going to give you +1 for the effort. But I'm ditching PATH_INFO now, I will just use REQUEST_URI in my scripts instead. For now, my problem is quite solved but I'm still interested in fixing that elusive PATH_INFO in case third party scripts rely on it.